# Dashboard: how to navigate the sidebar through a lot of items

Tags: usability, navigation, lists, filter, dropdown

I'm working on an analytical dashboard to help an owner of a restaurant chain to analyse performances of his restaurants. Restaurants could be filtered in groups, depending on places (ie "Show me all the restaurants in that city.").

I'm now thinking about a sidebar with a simple filter: a list of places with a checkbox to let user compare metrics about selected areas: therefore user can look at some graphs about transactions or revenues.

What if user want to analyse performances of just one restaurant? Can you suggest me an alternative to a dropdown list with a checkbox for each restaurant, as shown in the image?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accordion I would use classic tree view for filtering, and would enchance it with search on top.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3451253/65e27b11cab41dc251f842472a89e075

[image]

Comment: Could you include the image into your post?

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give to you is to gain a *thorough understanding* of the problem you are trying to solve. Ask yourself as much questions as possible and try to find satisfying answers.

For a start:

1. What is the kind of data you are visualising?
2. What attributes does the data have?
3. Which relations in the data are important?
4. How will the data be used?
5. What kind of insights does the user want from the data?

There are many more possible questions. Try to really understand the problem before spending too much time on specific solutions or design decisions.

You seem to have settled on a bar chart now, but another type of chart could be more appropriate. Maybe a [bubble map chart](http://datavizproject.com/data-type/bubble-map-chart/) or a [bar chart on a map](http://datavizproject.com/data-type/map-bar-chart/). I have no idea at this point, but you will find out soon enough once you research the problem.

I know a pretty generic answer, I cannot be more specific without knowing more about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Probably I didn't explain well the doubt I have:

-On one hand, user wants to see an overview about all the restaurants, based on places. Which place earned more revenues?

- On the other hand, user also wants to select each restaurant and see specific data. Same kind of graph, but more specific.

Therefore the problem is how to display in the sidebar all the restaurants, how the user can select them and navigate through them. Consider that it isn't possible to use a map, because it's now impossible.

Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: You could display a list of the restaurants. If the user doesn't select any of them, an overview will be shown. Maybe group them by area or some other attribute. Put a search box above the list if there are a lot of them. I'd narrow up the vertical spacing for the list items a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Willem, You should focus on the Dashboard overview page. Personally I would give a list of places there itself which are the user's favorite on the same page. 
The list could have most active restaurants based on percentage change or user defined criteria. 
Once the overview page is done you could have similar side bar with places in case user wants to dig to a particular restaurant